# Do "radiant" and "brilliant" rhyme for the purposes of poetry? Wiktionary says their transcriptions are /ˈɹeɪ.di.ənt/ and /ˈbɹɪljənt/

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, poetry, phonetics, syllables

Is this a dialectal/idiolectal thing, where some merge /i/ and /j/, and others don't? I'm ESL and always thought they're merged until now.

Comment: This is...tricky. I think either word can be pronounced with either 2 or 3 syllables.

Comment: Possibly. /ˈɹeɪ.djənt/  could be an Irish pronunciation. That said, in half-rhyme situations, even if the poet says the word *radiant* with three syllables, you might see it paired with *brilliant*, even if the poet pronounces the latter with only two syllables. https://www.britannica.com/art/half-rhyme

Comment: According to *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* the pronunciation "/ˈbrɪl.i.ənt/"is acceptable as an alternative to mainstream jod variant  (both Br and Am E).

Comment: They are never going to be perfect rhymes (because the stressed syllables in these words, *ray* and *brill*, don't have the same vowel) and even if you pronounce them with different numbers of syllables they're still reasonably good near-rhymes.

Comment: For strict rhyming, we want the last *accented syllable* plus all following syllables to sound the same.  With this standard, *radiant* and *brilliant* do not rhyme, even if the "-iant" parts are the same.  For example: *living* and *forgiving* would rhyme with each other, but they would not rhyme with *walking* and *talking*.

Comment: Joseph Addison (no Irishman, @Tim!) would seem to have pronounced *radiant* in just two syllables: "What though nor re-al voice nor sound / Amid their radiant orbs be found."

Comment: @BrianDonovan Maybe he picked that up from Swift :-)

Comment: Free verse doesn't require any rhymes at all, so 'for the purpose of poetry' is misleading, capet. As to how acceptable a person would find an 'attempted rhyme' using these two words, that's obviously a matter of opinion.

Comment: You need to think what kind of rhyme you want. Some poets/lyricists allow similar but not identical sounds, some follow strict requirements about full rhyme matching on stressed syllables, some do something else. And what precise dialect you speak will affect what rhymes: "caught" and "not" rhyme in Scotland but not in parts of England.

Answer (score 3):

This is a longish Comment , listing out my thoughts ....

(A) In a Poem , William Blake not only [wrote](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43687/the-tyger) the unusual "tyger" instead of the usual "tiger" , he even made "Eye" rhyme with "Symmetry" :

> **The Tyger**
> Tyger Tyger, burning bright,
> In the forests of the night;
> What immortal hand or **eye**,
> Could frame thy fearful **symmetry**?

Compared to that , "radiant" versus "brilliant" seems very normal & usual.

(B) WordWeb says :

[brilliant](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=brilliant) : bril-yunt [N. Amer], bri-lee-unt [Brit]

[radiant](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=radiant) : rey-dee-unt

(C) Not only American versus British , there are going to be Pronunciation variations in Canadian , Australian Etc.

(D) There is the concept of [eye rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_rhyme) , hence it is no big deal to worry over "radiant" versus "brilliant" , which is all fine to use in your Poetry.

(E) There is the [Poetic license](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/poetic%20license) to try out what-ever the Poet wants or wishes.

SUMMARY : you are good to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

*Radiant* and *brilliant* are words subject to what John Wells terms "compression", where disyllabic /i.ə/ and monosyllabic /jə/ are both possible in the same position. From his *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* (3rd ed., 2008, p. 173):

> 1. Sometimes a sequence of sounds has two possible pronunciations: either as two separate syllables, or **compressed** into a single syllable. Possible compressions are shown in this dictionary by the symbol ‿ between the syllables affected.
>
>    **lenient** ˈliːn i‿ənt Two pronunciations are possible: a slower one ˈliːn i ənt, and a faster one ˈliːn jənt. [...]
> 2. Generally the uncompressed version is more usual
>
>    - in rarer words
>    - in slow or deliberate speech
>    - the first time a word is used in a given discourse.
>
>    The compressed version is more usual
>
>    - in frequently used words
>    - in fast or casual speech
>    - if the word has already been used in the discourse.
> 3. When a syllable is compressed, one of the following phonetic changes takes place. (They are also exemplified in 1 above.)
>
>    - A weak vowel i or u is changed into the corresponding semivowel, j or w, producing in combination with the following vowel a crescendo DIPHTHONG. **influence** ˈɪn flu‿ənᵗs (= ˈɪn.flu.ənᵗs or ˈɪn.flwənᵗs) [...]